# "It was me who brought it (my puppy) up" or "It was me who brought up it"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, usage, word-order, phrasal-verbs

I've heard people use "It was me who brought it (my puppy) up" all the time and never heard of anybody use  "It was me who brought up it" because when using "object pronouns" with phrasal verbs, we use "him, her, it..." after the phrase.

Although I know this, I just wanted to make sure of it. So, can anybody tell me if it is right or wrong and if it is wrong, why?

Answer (score 1):

There are four basic types of phrasal verbs.

- transitive
- intransitive
- separable
- and inseparable

To bring up falls into two categories and can be used thusly:

**- I brought up my dog.
- I brought it up. 
- I brought the dog up.**

Please notice the position of the pronoun **it** standing for the dog. If you use the pronoun, it cannot go at the end.

bring up means to raise (a child, chickens, a dog)

and also means: to raise a subject. **He brought history up during our conversation**.

Its categories are that it is a transitive, separable phrasal verb with three meanings.

Third meaning:    He brought up the clothes from the dryer in the basement. [to move something to a higher level]

You can say: It was me that [did whatever] or It was I that [did whatever].

- I brought him up [child] in the elevator.

[phrasal verbs](https://www.studyandexam.com/types-of-phrasal-verb.html)

In all cases, **brought up it** is not grammatical in English. In this type of phrasal verb the pronoun has to go between the verb and the preposition.